# CSS DIV sticking out of another DIV

Tags: html, css

I have three DIV sections, two of them being subsection Left (For aligning to the left) and the one in the middle is subsection right (For aligning to the right). I use class for these DIVs and used `subSectionLeft` class for the first and third and `subSectionRight` for the second one. However, the top part of the third div section goes beyond the second section, causing it to stick out of the second one.

[This is the image of my problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NddH.jpg)

```css
#contentSection {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(236, 236, 236);
  margin-top: 2%;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
  padding-top: 2%;
  padding-bottom: 2%;
}

.subSectionLeft {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 2%;
  padding: 2%;
  padding-bottom: 12%;
  padding-left: 3%;
  background-color: red;
}

.subSectionLeft .sectionTitle {
  width: 60%;
  height: 60%;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
  background-color: rgb(236, 236, 236);
  float: left;
  display: block;
}

.subSectionLeft .sectionContent {
  width: 60%;
  height: 60%;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
  background-color: rgb(236, 236, 236);
}

.subSectionLeft .sectionIMG {
  width: 40%;
  float: right;
  background-color: rgb(236, 236, 236);
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  margin: auto;
}

.subSectionLeft .sectionIMG img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.subSectionRight {
  width: 90%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 2%;
  padding: 2%;
  padding-bottom: 12%;
  padding-left: 3%;
  background-color: rgb(236, 236, 236);
  float: left;
  display: block;
}

.subSectionRight .sectionTitle {
  width: 60%;
  height: 60%;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
  background-color: rgb(236, 236, 236);
  float: right;
  display: block;
  text-align: right;
}

.subSectionRight .sectionContent {
  width: 60%;
  height: 60%;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
  background-color: rgb(236, 236, 236);
  left: 60%;
  float: right;
  display: block;
  text-align: right;
}

.subSectionRight .sectionIMG {
  width: 40%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  background-color: rgb(236, 236, 236);
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}

.subSectionRight .sectionIMG img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="subSectionLeft">
  <div class="sectionTitle">
    <h1>Advanced & Innovative Technology</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="sectionIMG">
    <img src="../IMAGES/hardboilder.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="sectionContent">
    <h3>
      Voila cars use technologies developed by world-class engineers who aim to create the best mode of transportation for you.
    </h3>
  </div>

</div>

<div class="subSectionRight">
  <div class="sectionTitle">
    <h1>Impeccable Modern Style</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="sectionIMG">
    <img src="../IMAGES/Hyundai-Prophecy.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="sectionContent">
    <h3>Modern and Elegant. Voila cars are designed with these ideas in mind and deliver only the best of the best for you.</h3>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="subSectionLeft">
  <div class="sectionTitle">
    <h1>Environmental Friendly</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="sectionIMG">
    <img src="../IMAGES/Green-Car.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="sectionContent">
    <h3>Voila cars use environmental friendly technologies, allowing us to protect and improve the condition of the beautiful gift of nature around us.</h3>
  </div>

</div>
```

Does anyone have any idea how I can solve this?

Comment: Can you please add an image of desired outcome? It's not clear reading your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to add float property to your image or paragraph which you've already added. So there is no point of `float:left;` on the `subSectionRight` class as far as I understand from your code.

By removing `float:left;` from the `subSectionRight` solved your problem when I tested with given HTML and CSS.

Comment: Thank you very much! It solved my problem :D:D